# Method or technique to extract metadata from video

Tags: video, methods, location, metadata, avi

I would like to extract some properties and metadata from videos file(to be exact video in AVI format, why AVI format?  it is because I get this video files from dashcam).

- location(latitude,longitude)
- speed
- date

is there any technique or method that can extract this metadata? **method and technique** not metadata extraction tools. I'm going to develop a system that can extract metadata from dashcam video. So, I want to apply any method or technique

Is **video analysis**, **video abstraction**, **video retrieval** is types of method or technique to gain metadata from a video?